# Every second word in python

Tags: python

Is there a way to do this: 
So you have a list of names like:
list = "James", "Bond", "David", "Beckham", "Selena", "Gomez" 
Can you do something so it prints every second word together like:
"James Bond"
"David Beckham"
"Selena Gomez"

Comment: Post whatever code you've already got, even if it's just the array definition and a line with a comment which says "and here's where I need to print my stuff".

Comment: name_num = ""
position = 0
while position == 0:
    name = input("Student name")
    number = int(input("Student number"))
    position = int(input("Enter position number"))
    name_num += name + " "
print(name_num)
name_num.split()
thing = name_num.split()
for word in thing:
    print(word)
print(thing)
 and i want it to print each name on a seperate line, but if someone writes a first and last name, it mucks it up and prints the first and last name on separate lines

Answer (score 2):

Sure, with slicing:

```
names = ["James", "Bond", ... ]
for first_name, last_name in zip(names[::2], names[1::2]):
    print first_name + " " + last_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply separate the first name and last name and then use `zip`

```
>>> given_list = ["James", "Bond", "David", "Beckham", "Selena", "Gomez"]
>>> [" ".join(i) for i in zip(given_list[::2], given_list[1::2])]
['James Bond', 'David Beckham', 'Selena Gomez']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ["James", "Bond", "David", "Beckham", "Selena", "Gomez"]
i = 0
j = i+1
result = []
while i <= len(list):
    if j >= len(list):
        break
    result.append(list[i] + " " + list[j])
    i = i+2
    j = i+1

print result
```

Result

```
['James Bond', 'David Beckham', 'Selena Gomez']
```